# Android how to totally disable scrolling status bar down

Tags: android, statusbar, disable

I am trying to disable the status bar and not allowing the user to expand it at all.
I tried a few methods and it is working good but not on resume!
On resume, if I quickly tried to expand it i could do that!

Any help!

Comment: share code of what you tried!!!

Comment: mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);